# Add days to dates in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am stymied at the moment.  I am sure that I am missing something simple, but how do you move a series of dates forward by x units?  In my more specific case I want to add 180 days to a date series within a dataframe.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import pandas, numpy, StringIO, datetime


txt = '''ID,DATE
002691c9cec109e64558848f1358ac16,2003-08-13 00:00:00
002691c9cec109e64558848f1358ac16,2003-08-13 00:00:00
0088f218a1f00e0fe1b94919dc68ec33,2006-05-07 00:00:00
0088f218a1f00e0fe1b94919dc68ec33,2006-06-03 00:00:00
00d34668025906d55ae2e529615f530a,2006-03-09 00:00:00
00d34668025906d55ae2e529615f530a,2006-03-09 00:00:00
0101d3286dfbd58642a7527ecbddb92e,2007-10-13 00:00:00
0101d3286dfbd58642a7527ecbddb92e,2007-10-27 00:00:00
0103bd73af66e5a44f7867c0bb2203cc,2001-02-01 00:00:00
0103bd73af66e5a44f7867c0bb2203cc,2008-01-20 00:00:00
'''
df = pandas.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(txt))
df = df.sort('DATE')
df.DATE = pandas.to_datetime(df.DATE)
df['X_DATE'] = df['DATE'].shift(180, freq=pandas.datetools.Day)
```

This code generates a type error.  For reference I am using:

```
Python 2.7.4
Pandas '0.12.0.dev-6e7c4d6'
Numpy '1.7.1'
```

Comment: Please post the error with the traceback so we can see what your problem is. Also, if you want to add 180 dates, what do you want the ID's for those rows to be? `Nan`?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

If I understand you, you don't actually want `shift`, you simply want to make a new column next to the existing `DATE` which is 180 days after.  In that case, you can use `timedelta`:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> df.head()
                                 ID                DATE
8  0103bd73af66e5a44f7867c0bb2203cc 2001-02-01 00:00:00
0  002691c9cec109e64558848f1358ac16 2003-08-13 00:00:00
1  002691c9cec109e64558848f1358ac16 2003-08-13 00:00:00
5  00d34668025906d55ae2e529615f530a 2006-03-09 00:00:00
4  00d34668025906d55ae2e529615f530a 2006-03-09 00:00:00
>>> df["X_DATE"] = df["DATE"] + timedelta(days=180)
>>> df.head()
                                 ID                DATE              X_DATE
8  0103bd73af66e5a44f7867c0bb2203cc 2001-02-01 00:00:00 2001-07-31 00:00:00
0  002691c9cec109e64558848f1358ac16 2003-08-13 00:00:00 2004-02-09 00:00:00
1  002691c9cec109e64558848f1358ac16 2003-08-13 00:00:00 2004-02-09 00:00:00
5  00d34668025906d55ae2e529615f530a 2006-03-09 00:00:00 2006-09-05 00:00:00
4  00d34668025906d55ae2e529615f530a 2006-03-09 00:00:00 2006-09-05 00:00:00
```

Does that help any?

Answer (score 91):

You could use `pd.DateOffset`. Which seems to be faster than `timedelta`.

```
In [930]: df['x_DATE'] = df['DATE'] + pd.DateOffset(days=180)

In [931]: df
Out[931]:
                                 ID       DATE     x_DATE
8  0103bd73af66e5a44f7867c0bb2203cc 2001-02-01 2001-07-31
0  002691c9cec109e64558848f1358ac16 2003-08-13 2004-02-09
1  002691c9cec109e64558848f1358ac16 2003-08-13 2004-02-09
4  00d34668025906d55ae2e529615f530a 2006-03-09 2006-09-05
5  00d34668025906d55ae2e529615f530a 2006-03-09 2006-09-05
2  0088f218a1f00e0fe1b94919dc68ec33 2006-05-07 2006-11-03
3  0088f218a1f00e0fe1b94919dc68ec33 2006-06-03 2006-11-30
6  0101d3286dfbd58642a7527ecbddb92e 2007-10-13 2008-04-10
7  0101d3286dfbd58642a7527ecbddb92e 2007-10-27 2008-04-24
9  0103bd73af66e5a44f7867c0bb2203cc 2008-01-20 2008-07-18
```

---

Timings

<sub>Medium</sub>

```
In [948]: df.shape
Out[948]: (10000, 3)

In [950]: %timeit df['DATE'] + pd.DateOffset(days=180)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.51 ms per loop

In [949]: %timeit df['DATE'] + timedelta(days=180)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.71 ms per loop
```

<sub>Large</sub>

```
In [952]: df.shape
Out[952]: (100000, 3)

In [953]: %timeit df['DATE'] + pd.DateOffset(days=180)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.16 ms per loop

In [955]: %timeit df['DATE'] + timedelta(days=180)
10 loops, best of 3: 20 ms per loop
```

Comment: Odd that it would be faster since DateOffset itself uses timedelta?

Answer (score 34):

For future readers if you want to change different rows by different amounts you will need to use Pandas TimedeltaIndex instead to pass a series of timedeltas.

For example I might want to shift my data to the nearest report period and each record could have started on a different day of the week.

```
import pandas as pd
days_to_shift = pd.TimedeltaIndex(6 - launch_df['launch_dt'].dt.dayofweek)
launch_df['launch_dt'] = launch_df['launch_dt'] + days_to_shift
```

Comment: To add **days** (instead of nanoseconds, which was the default in my test), you may need to add a unit arg, like so:
`days_to_shift = pd.TimedeltaIndex(6 - launch_df["launch_dt"].dt.dayofweek, unit="D")`