# pandas add column of different days to datetime column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this.

```
                          time  daysToExp
0   2020-08-11 13:53:57.083388          0
1   2020-08-11 13:53:57.083388          1
2   2020-08-11 13:53:57.083388          3
3   2020-08-11 13:53:57.083388          4
4   2020-08-11 13:53:57.083388          8
```

I would like to add the daysToExp column to the time column and end with a result to something like this.

```
                          time  daysToExp                         Date
0   2020-08-11 13:53:57.083388          0   2020-08-11 13:53:57.083388
1   2020-08-11 13:53:57.083388          1   2020-08-12 13:53:57.083388
2   2020-08-11 13:53:57.083388          3   2020-08-14 13:53:57.083388
3   2020-08-11 13:53:57.083388          4   2020-08-15 13:53:57.083388
4   2020-08-11 13:53:57.083388          8   2020-08-19 13:53:57.083388
```

The closest command I found is this, `df['Date'] = df['time'] + pd.DateOffset(days=3)`but it cannot do an entire column in a DataFrame. What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39962299/10741023

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: add timedelta column to datetime column (vectorized)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355816/pandas-add-timedelta-column-to-datetime-column-vectorized)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.to_timedelta`:

```
df['time'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['daysToExp'], unit='D')
```

or equivalently:

```
df['time'] + pd.to_timedelta('1D') * df['daysToExp']
```